# Why $f(x)=x$ is not bounded on $(0,1)$?

Tags: calculus

This is perhaps the most stupid question ever asked here but I do not understand why $f(x)=x$ is not bounded on $(0,1)$? or why $f(x)=-(x-2)(x-3)$ has no minimum on $(2,3)$?

Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: Can you find a number in $(0,1)$ that is greater than or equal to all elements of $(0,1)$? What about with $[0,1]$ or $(0,1]$? Thinking about this might set you on the right track.

Comment: If the interval is $[0,1]$, you are right but there can't be maximum on the interval $(0,1)$ because whatever number you choose as maximum, one can show that that number plus $\epsilon$ is greater than that for suitable $\epsilon$.

Comment: For clarity: a function $f(x): \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is *bounded* over some domain $D$ if there exist $c,d\in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x$ in $D$, $c \leq f(x) \leq d$.  In other words, there exists both an upper and a lower bound of the function over that interval.

Next, the notation $(0,1)$ refers to the set of all points $x$ such that $0 < x < 1$.  On the other hand, $[0,1]$ refers to the set of points $x$ such that $0 \leq x \leq 1$, and $[0,1)$ is the set of points such that $0 \leq x < 1$.

Hopefully these definitions help clarify things.

Comment: What is the codomain of $f$?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the codomain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

Then the function $f(x) = x$ is bounded in $(0, 1)$ by definition, because in this interval $|f(x)| < 1$. As @DanielFischer pointed out in comments, in case $f(x)$ has $(0, 1)$ codomain, the function $f$ wouldn't be bounded in $(0, 1)$.

The function $f(x) = -(x-2)(x-3)$ is also bounded because of the same reason, but it doesn't have a minimum in $(2, 3)$ because it can take value arbitrarily close to $0$, but always greater than $0$ in this interval. The function achieves $0$ in $x=2$ or $x=3$, but these points both are not included in the domain.

Comment: That depends on what the _codomain_ is. If the codomain is $\mathbb{R}$, it's bounded. If the codomain is $(0,1)$, it isn't.

Comment: @DanielFischer What statement in my answer are you referring to?

Comment: The statement that $f$ is bounded. Whether or not it is depends on the codomain of $f$.

Comment: @DanielFischer You're technically correct, and of course technically correct is important. But I think the usual convention in analysis in a question like this  is that functions are "real valued", so the codomain is (implicitly) $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for pointing that out. I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

**No one** can tell you "why f(x)= x is not bounded on (0, 1)" because it **is** bounded!  -1 is a lower bound and 2 is an upper bound.  We can even say that 0 is the "greatest lower bound" and 1 is the "least upper bound".

Where did you get the idea that it was not bounded?  It is true that f(x)= x has no "maximum" or "minimum" on (0, 1) but that does not mean it is not bounded.

We can write $-(x- 2)(x- 3)$ as $-(x^2- 5x+ 3)$ and complete the square: $-(x^2- 5x+ \frac{25}{4}- \frac{25}{4}+ \frac{12}{4})= -(x-\frac{5}{2})^2+ \frac{13}{4}$.  That is a parabola opening downward.  Its **maximum** occurs when $x= \frac{25}{4}$ and is $\frac{13}{4}$. Since x  in the interval (2, 3) can come arbitrarily close to 2 and 3 but not equal to them f(x) can come arbitrarily close to 0 but not equal to it.

Answer (score 0):

The identity function $f(x)=x$ *is* bounded on $(0,1)$: every value is less than $100$. The fact that the bound isn't in the image is irrelevant.

The second function in your question is bounded below on the interval in question. Since it's always positive, $0$ is a lower bound. But there is no place where that  bound is the value of the function. There is no smallest value for that domain.

Comment: That depends on what the _codomain_ is. If the codomain is $\mathbb{R}$, it's bounded. If the codomain is $(0,1)$, it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

1. If $f(x)=x$  then we have $0<f(x)<1$ for all $x \in (0,1)$. This gives: $f$ is bounded on $(0,1)$.
2. If $f(x)=-(x-2)(x-3)$ then $f(x)>0$ for all $x \in (2,3)$ and $0 = \inf\{f(x): x \in (2,3)\}$. Suppose that $f$ has a minimum at $x_0 \in (2,3)$. Then $f(x_0)=0$, a contradiction , since $f$ has only $2$ zeroes.